# Custom scrolling on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, html5-canvas

What is the recommended way to provide scrolling and native scrollbars for very large data displayed in an hmtl5 canvas?

I need to display data that is 128000x128000 pixels. Using a canvas with width/height set to 128000 is not an option as that would use an enormous amount of RAM (around 61 GB according to my quick calculation).

So I need a way to provide custom scrollbars for an HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Well, if the canvas is drawing the scrollbar, then it won't really be native. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm basically looking for a way to display a native scrollbar that I can catch scroll events from. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jCanvas](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jcanvas-canvas-manipulation-with-jquery)** is a jQuery plugin which may help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately I couldn't find any native support for it in jCanvas, but it does have some other very nice things. I ended up doing a zoom thing instead, inspired by how google maps operate.

Comment: Alright then. Hope I helped you. Consider up-voting and accepting my answer to make others understand that my answer helped you.

Answer (score 5):

After a quick test, I'm not sure Chrome or Firefox will even render a canvas that big.
My bet would be to create a canvas element but never append it to the DOM. Just like this:

```
var hiddenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
hiddenCanvas.width = 128000;
hiddenCanvas.height = 128000;
var hiddenContext = hiddenCanvas.getContext('2d');
```

Then create a smaller canvas that will actually display a portion of your hidden canvas

```
<canvas width="something reasonable" height="something reasonable" id="viewCanvas"/>
```

And use the drawImage method to draw portions:

```
var viewCanvas = document.getElementById('viewCanvas');
var viewContext = viewCanvas.getContext('2d');
viewCanvasContext.drawImage(hiddenCanvas, 40, 50, viewCanvas.width, viewCanvas.height, 0, 0, viewCanvas.width, viewCanvas.height);
```

Then it would be up to you to either provide up/down/right/left buttons to navigate, or maybe fake scrollbars by using 20px wide DIVs that would only show scrollbars and which you would hook an onscroll even listener on.
And each time the user changes position, do a call again to drawImage, updating the x/y positions (40 and 50 in my example).

Having said this, again, even when hidden I doubt that browsers will work with a canvas that big.

I happen to be looking for a solution to the same problem, so if in your research you get lucky, please share.

Comment: I solved my problem with a zoom function. Setting the width and height to 100% and then doing zoom in / zoom out & drag with the mouse. It does add some additional complexity to the application / user experience though. Also, rendering a huge chunk of data, even on a smaller canvas can sometimes take some time. A 60000x60000 chunk scaled down to for instance a 1000x1000 canvas generally takes 2-3 seconds to draw.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I haven’t used `<canvas>` very much, but I believe the inside of the `<canvas>` is best thought of like an image, i.e. it’s a black box as far as the DOM is concerned.

As such, I don’t think you can really scroll it in the way that you’re imagining. If you had a 128000×128000 `<canvas>`, you could put it inside a `<div>` that’s e.g. 1280×1280 and set that `<div>` to `overflow:hidden`, but as you say, a 128000×128000 `<canvas>` is impractical.

I guess the kind of solution you’re looking for would provide a virtual 128000×128000 canvas interface, but then split it up into chunks, provide a scroll interface, and draw in each chunk as it was scrolled into view.